# Get the list of child if the selected value is same value as in the Firebase database value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database is as following :

```
List_of_users>
             sunil dhakal>
                        departmnet:"Computer Science",
                        level:"Level 3 Undergraduate",
                        name:"sunil dhakal",
                        student_id:"1412361",
                        username:"1412361@my.brunel.ac.uk",
```

---

```
root.child("List_of_user").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot data :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            if (data.child(department).exists()&& data.child(level).exists()){
                Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                Iterator i = dataSnapshot.child("List_of_users").getChildren().iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    set.add(((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getKey());
                }
                list_of_rooms.clear();
                list_of_rooms.addAll(set);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(searchuser.this,"There is not user with the department and level that was selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

I have a spinner where user is able to select department and level and click a button which list all the user in the database with that department and level.

Answer (score 0):

Use a firebase query to get them:

```
firebaseReference.child("List_of_users")
                 .orderByChild("department")
                 .equalTo("valueInSpinner")
                 .orderByChild("level")
                 .equalTo("valueInSpinner")
```

Then you could use that with an Adapter to bind it to a ListView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you can you please provide me with the how the code can be implemented as I have tried many attempt to make it work

Answer (score 0):

searchusers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String department = dep.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            final String level = lev.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    root.child("List_of_users")
                            .orderByChild("department")
                            .equalTo(department)
                            .orderByChild("level")
                            .equalTo(level);
                    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.child("List_of_users").getChildren().iterator();
                    while (i.hasNext()) {
                        set.add(((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getKey());
                    }
                    list_of_rooms.clear();
                    list_of_rooms.addAll(set);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

Is this format ok?